# OpenGL independent translation after doing translation+rotation?

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, geometry, rotation

I want to acheive translations/rotations as shown in following video -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92h0xuV4Yrg

I know for independant translation and rotation, typical method is - first rotate the object and then translate.

As shown  here:

```
PushMatrix();
LoadIdentity(); 
Translate(posx,posy,posz);     // Second, move the object to its final destination
Rotate();        // First, apply rotations (which rotate around object-origin
Draw();         
PopMatrix();
```

But my requirment is to rotate the object around world-coordinate and move it using mouse.

As seen in the video, the rotation is done around the world-origin not around object-origin.That means the logic should be opposite to above (first translate and then do the rotation)

```
PushMatrix();
LoadIdentity(); 
Rotate();        // Second, apply rotations (which rotate around world-origin)
Translate(posx,posy,posz);     // First, move the object to its final destination
Draw();         
PopMatrix();
```

But the,final translation in the video is done relative to final position after the rotations.(which is not same as the posx,posy,posz values I manipulate using mouse ).

How to achive this kind of translations

Comment: Is the final translation in world space or object space? If it's in object space then you can just push another matrix on the stack and move it.

Comment: all translations are in the world space.

Comment: I can't follow your question, are you just trying to rotate an object around an arbitrary position?

Comment: simply,my question is how to implement user interactions as shown in the video.

Answer (score 2):

To rotate an object around any point (x,y,z), you do the following:

```
translate (-x,-y,-z);
rotate (angle);
translate (x, y, z);
```

That point doesn't have to be a point on the object. It can be the origin, or any random value like (1000, 0.0023, 97.5). You may have to do an additional translation in your case. For example, if your object is defined at the origin, and the user has placed it at (x1,y1,z1) and you want to rotate it around (x,y,z), you'll need to add a:

```
translate (x1,y1,z1);
```

after the translate (x,y,z).

Comment: still this doesnt solve my problem.Heres what i d-.When user moves mouse left/righ,t I increment/decrement  the "posX" variable.When user moves mouse up/down I increment/decrement the "posY" variable.When user drag the mouse I rotate my object.So my translations should always be correspond to the mouse movement.That is left/right movement controls X value and up/down controls Y value.But after any rotation around (posX,posY,posZ)  this doesnt work.